# When an inherited widget changes Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to show weekly content to users on the home screen of my app.

The content needs to be updated on the specified day of the week.

I'm getting an error "When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
E/flutter ( 3563): Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter."

Code:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animation();
    checkUpdate();
    displaySplash();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void animation() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..repeat(reverse: true);

    _animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  void checkUpdate() async {
    //int? isUpdate = Config.sharedPreferences!.getInt(isUpdateRecommendedDay);

    dateTime.weekday == 2 ? update() : pass();

    setProviders();
  }

  void pass() async {
    _isUpdate = false;

    await Provider.of<RecommendedContentNotifier>(context, listen: false)
        .getRecommendedContent(isUpdate: false);
  }

  void update() async {
    _isUpdate = true;
    await Provider.of<RecommendedContentNotifier>(context, listen: true)
        .getRecommendedContent(isUpdate: true);

    await Provider.of<DatabaseContentNotifier>(context, listen: false)
        .getLastId();

    await Config.sharedPreferences!
        .setInt(isUpdateRecommendedDay, dateTime.weekday);
  }

  void setProviders() async {
    await Provider.of<CheckInternetConnectionNotifier>(context, listen: false)
        .checkConnectivity();
    await Provider.of<RecommendedContentNotifier>(context, listen: false)
        .loadRecommendedVideoInfoNotifier();
    await Provider.of<DatabaseContentNotifier>(context, listen: false)
        .getAllContentSize();
    await Provider.of<DatabaseContentNotifier>(context, listen: false)
        .getDiscoverContent(
            context.read<DatabaseContentNotifier>().allContentSize);

    await Provider.of<FontSizeNotifier>(context, listen: false).loadFontSize();
  }

  void displaySplash() async {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

    /// !
    Timer(Duration(seconds: _isUpdate ? 10 : 3), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MainPage()));

      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
          overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);
    });
  }
```

And my update method:

```
Future<List<ContentModel>> getRecommendedContent(
      {required bool isUpdate}) async {
    /*final List<String>? _startAfter =
        Config.sharedPreferences!.getStringList(startAfter);*/

    if (isUpdate == true) {
      /// Config.sharedPreferences!.getStringList(startAfter)!.last mevcut son içerik id

      _recommendedDataList = await AllContentDatabaseHelper.instance
          .getRecommendedContent(
              Config.sharedPreferences!.getStringList(startAfter)!.last);

      Config.sharedPreferences!.setStringList(startAfter, [
        Config.sharedPreferences!.getStringList(startAfter)!.last,
        _recommendedDataList.last.contentId
      ]);
    } else {
      _recommendedDataList = await AllContentDatabaseHelper.instance
          .getRecommendedContent(
              Config.sharedPreferences!.getStringList(startAfter)!.first);
    }

    notifyListeners();

    return _recommendedDataList;
  }
```

How do I implement the didChangeDependencies method?

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to do all this in a `Widget`.

Use application state management (BLoC, GetX, etc.) to hold and update the information, and build a simple stateless widget tree to display it.